How to retrieve value from another widget in flutter?
I have tried to make an image picker widget, I named it ImagePickerWidget, it looks like this
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(widget.label),
        VerticalSeparator(height: 1),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            XFile? imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            if(imageFile != null){
              setState(() {
                image = File(imageFile.path);
              });
            }
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*20,
            height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*20,
            child: image!=null?
              Image.file(image!, fit: BoxFit.cover,):
              Image.asset('assets/illustration/ill_add_photo.png', package: 'design_module', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          )
        )
      ],
    )

I will call this widget every time I need image picker on my forms(CustomFormWidget), but I have trouble to send the image value in ImagePickerWidget to CustomFormWidget. I am thinking making it like onChanged method on TextFormField where I can get the value through function parameter. Any idea?

Your question isn't too clear, but I think you want to make a reusable widget and pass the picked file as the result.
Simply accept a callback/function:
class MyImagePickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(File?) onChanged; // --> add this

  MyImagePickerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);
}

and then, in the onTap of the InkWell, call the function:
onTap: () async {
  XFile? imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if(imageFile != null){
    setState(() {
      image = File(imageFile.path);
    });
    widget.onChanged(image); // --> Call onChanged here.
  }
},

and its' usage would be;
MyImagePickerWidget(
  onChanged: (File? file) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedImage = file;
    });
  },
),


Complete example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomFormWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomFormWidgetState createState() => _CustomFormWidgetState();
}

class _CustomFormWidgetState extends State<CustomFormWidget> {
  File? _selectedImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          MyImagePickerWidget(
            onChanged: (File? file) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedImage = file;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(_selectedImage != null 
              ? 'Image selected: ${_selectedImage!.path}'
              : 'No image selected'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyImagePickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(File?) onChanged;

  const MyImagePickerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyImagePickerWidgetState createState() => _MyImagePickerWidgetState();
}

class _MyImagePickerWidgetState extends State<MyImagePickerWidget> {
  File? image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    image = widget.initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(widget.label),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            XFile? imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if(imageFile != null){
              setState(() {
                image = File(imageFile.path);
              });
              widget.onChanged(image);
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            child: image != null
              ? Image.file(image!, fit: BoxFit.cover)
              : Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 50),
          )
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


It works, thanks a lot
